# Node.js сервер некорректно отдаёт файлы

Tags: node.js, javascript

Задача, примитивнейший веб сервер на ноде. Есть html страничка которую нужно отдать, в ней есть подключение css и js файлов. Сам сервер:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

global['request'] = request;
global['response'] = response;

pathname = base + request.url;

path.exists(pathname,function(exists){
    if(exists){
        response.setHeader('Content-Type',mime.lookup(pathname));
        response.statusCode = 200;
        fs.readFile(pathname, function (err, data) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            response.write(data);
            response.end();
          });
    }else{
        routResponse(request,response);
    }
});
}).listen(8123);
```

Работает, html отдаёт нормально, если набрать адрес css файла или js файла то содержимое отдаётся корректно, однако при загрузке html страницы с подключёнными css и js файлами, вместо css может вывестись содержимое js файла или наоборот. Скорее всего гдето при чтении файла нужно что то обнулять, но инфы пока не нашёл на эту тему, может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Укажите абсолютные пути.

Comment: мне так кажется, что всё из-за какой-то идеи с global - global здесь нельзя, даже не надейтесь.

Comment: @Deadik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать модуль [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) и вы получите очень простой 
и удобный для дальнейшего расширения веб-сервер, который может обрабатывать не только
статику:

```
var port = 8080;
var express = require('express');
var compress = require('compression'); // gzip
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors()); // включает Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
var cacheTime = 86400000 * 7; 
// включаем gzip сжатие для статики
app.use(compress({
    threshold: 512
}));
// включаем кеширование статики
app.use(express.static(__dirname, {
    maxAge: cacheTime
}));

// ради безопасности скрываем информацию о себе
app.disable('x-powered-by');

// слушаем
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: express использовал и вполне устраивает. Интересно просто как задачу решить без него.

Answer (score 0):

У меня обычно как-то так. Тут, конечно, всё выдрано, но по идее должно работать :D

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var pathname = base + decodeURIComponent((request.url+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));

    path.exists(pathname,function(exists) {
        if(exists) {

            if (fs.statSync(pathname).isDirectory()) {
                pathname = './404.html';
            }
            else {
                fs.readFile(pathname, "binary", function(err, file) {
                    if(err) {
                        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
                        response.end(err + "\n");
                        return;
                    }

                    fs.stat(pathname, function(err, stat) {
                        response.setHeader('Content-Type', mime.lookup(pathname));
                        response.setHeader('Last-Modified', stat.mtime);

                        if(request.headers['if-none-match'] === etag) {
                            response.statusCode = 304;
                            response.end();
                        }
                        else {
                            var etag = stat.size + '-' + Date.parse(stat.mtime);
                            response.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
                            response.setHeader('ETag', etag);

                            response.writeHead(200);
                            response.write(file, "binary");
                            response.end();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }else{
            routResponse(request,response);
        }
    });
}).listen(8123);
```

Comment: Посмотрел полный свой говнокод. Вроде всё так же обрабатывается, но пеочему то если в head подключается несколько файлов js и css то контент этих файлов подгружается неверный, например если подряд идёт подключение css и js то по адресу js файла подгружается код из css. Ладно, потом может разберусь, всё равно express использую

Comment: @Deadik скорее всего у вас pathname как глобальный. Подкрепите знания с областями видимости переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Есть мнение что из-за global и асинхронной природы ноды, когда идет несколько запросов, request и response хранят объекты последнего запроса (а в это время первый мог еще не успеть обработаться, и последний получает на выход данные предназначенные для первого и т.д.)

Comment: если убрать строки с global все должно работать